# Downloading a file directly via a Link in HTML/Android-Studio

Tags: html, android-studio

I'm trying to download a file from a link in an HTML file in an Android Studio
Scenario:

Press on "Download" to download an APK file:

```
<a href="https://myLink.com/mybuild.apk" download="Prod version">Download</a>
```

I tried with opening google or other pages - it works.
And yes, my link is correct :D

Comment: Perhaps remove the space in "Prod version" ?

Comment: Thats only a download name. Removing space doesn't fix the problem. When I launch this html file in browser I can download it without a problem, but when Im launching it in android studio it does nothing

Comment: So it is likely not supported or blocked for security reasons